# cant connect to local database using external IP:Port

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose, ufw

I have 2 Servers, `A` and `B`.

They both run the same replicated server-application (rest-API) written in `go`. On `Server B`, I also have a database running. Both server and database in `docker-containers`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...

 userDB:
      image: mysql:oracle
      restart: always
      container_name: userDB
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
        MYSQL_USER: 'user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'mypw
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'myrootpw'
      cap_add:
        - SYS_NICE
      ports:
        - '3307:3306'
      networks:
        - dbnet
...


go_rest:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./goREST/Dockerfile
    container_name: go_rest
    command: ["./goREST"]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - dbnet
```

Inside the Server, I connect to the database like so:

```
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:myrootpw@tcp(bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:3307)/mydb")


    var usr DBUser
    stmt, _ := db.Prepare(`SELECT * from user;`)
    _ = stmt.QueryRow().Scan(&usr.SteamId)
    log.Println(*usr.SteamId)
```

note, that the `bbb.bbb....` is the public IP of my `Server B`.

Now the problem:

Running th server-application on `Server A` (which doesn't have the database), **works fine**. I can also connect to the database from my development machine using this command:

`ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3307 usr@bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb`

But when using dockerized version on the machine which holds the database, I can't connect to the database? This only happens, when running inside docker, when I just run the executable like `./goRest` on `Server B`, it also works fine. I am really confused.

In case my explanation was confusing:

```
A -----> B(docker) works
B -----> B(local) works
B -----> B(docker) doesn not work

(docker) referes to the server-application. The database is always dockerized.
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04LTS

**EDIT**

The error that occurs looks like this:

```
rest  | 2022/08/29 22:54:00 http: panic serving ......6:45264: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
rest  | goroutine 9 [running]:
rest  | net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0000eefa0)
rest  |     /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1805 +0x153
rest  | panic(0x7d9900, 0xbb2e50)
rest  |     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:971 +0x499
rest  | database/sql.(*Stmt).QueryContext(0x0, 0x9b5b10, 0xc00001a088, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
rest  |     /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2630 +0x63
rest  | database/sql.(*Stmt).QueryRowContext(0x0, 0x9b5b10, 0xc00001a088, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9af7a0)
rest  |     /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2705 +0x6d
```

Comment: Are you checking whethr `err` is `nil`?  Looks like you're ignoring an rror, then attempting to access `db`.  Catch and panic on `err` so we can see the *real* error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a solution.

So the problem was with `ufw`. I had rules like this:

```
3307                       ALLOW       aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
3307                       ALLOW       prod.local.ip.notebook
3307                       ALLOW       bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
```

That's why the acces from my local development computer (aka. `prod.local.ip.notebook`) and the access from `server A` (aka aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa) **works**

The problem was bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb, because the container with the rest-API accessing the database was not allowed in `ufw`. To allow this IP, I had to get the container's `IP`.

So I ran: `docker exec -it xyz /bin/sh`, then inside the container: `ifconfig` which returned `172.22.0.5` for `eth0`.

This is the IP which had to be added to `ufw`. So my new `ufw` configuration looks like this:

```
3307                       ALLOW       aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa <- remote server
3307                       ALLOW       prod.local.ip.notebook <- development
3307                       ALLOW       bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
3307                       ALLOW       172.22.0.5 <- container ip
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:3307` with `userDB:3306` when running inside Docker. Try to make that a parameter that you pass at runtime, this way you don't have to change the code when you run with or without Docker.

Also you don't have to map port 3306 unless you want to connect to the database with some external tool. Your dockerized application doesn't need it.

Comment: this does not work unfortunately.. I am running another database on port `3306`, that's why I use port `3307`. I need to map them, because I am using external tools and I want to access the database from another server, in my example this server with remote access to the DB is `Server A`

Comment: just try it. you can keep your mapping for port 3307, but your containers talk on internal ports not on host ports.

Comment: I did and it didnt work, I managed it myself, I will post the answer soon. Thanks anyways !